# Handling OPTIONS for pre-flight request

Tags: magento2, rest-api

I'm attempting to send a **POST request** to a **Magento 2 API** that my co-worker launched. It's up and working. I've been able to get a response via curl, but because of pre-flight requests from the client I haven't been able to get a response.

Now, I know about the headers. We have `'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'` set already. The issue is that the OPTIONS request is being sent to determine the safety of the request (see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests)). Is there a way to handle this pre-flight OPTIONS request? If so, how?

Here's the other thing: my co-worker is receiving a response via curl, Ajax, and Ember.

Answer (score 1):

A CORS preflight request is a CORS request that checks to see if the CORS protocol is understood.

It is an OPTIONS request, using three HTTP request headers: Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers, and the Origin header.

A preflight request is automatically issued by a browser when needed. In normal cases, front-end developers don't need to craft such requests themselves.

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request

**Magento 2 Api does not support pre-flight request by default**. You can modify the apache or nginx server config for handling the request.
For example http://snippi.com/s/or2myzn

I would suggest installing the following module for handling the CORS pre-flight request in Magento 2 Api:
https://github.com/splashlab/magento-2-cors-requests